# Masonry script is blocking another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict, overwrite

I was working on a website, I have a bunch of scripts working fine next to each other.

I implemented another masonry script, which works fine by itself, but when I put them with another script, I get an error in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input masonry.js:16 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colladjust'
```

There might be some kind of collision of id or class variables.  Or overwriting of objects.

Here is the masonry script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var CollManag = (function() {
    var $ctCollContainer = $('#ct-coll-container'),
    collCnt = 1,
    init = function() {
        changeColCnt();
        initEvents();
        initPlugins();
    },
    changeColCnt = function() {
        var w_w = $(window).width();
        if( w_w <= 640 ) n = 1;
        else if( w_w <= 1023 ) n = 2;
        else n = 3;
    },
    initEvents = function() {
        $(window).on( 'smartresize.CollManag', function( event ) {
            changeColCnt();
        });
    },
    initPlugins = function() {
        $ctCollContainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $ctCollContainer.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.ct-coll-item',
                columnWidth : function( containerWidth ) {
                    return containerWidth / n;
                },
                isAnimated : true,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 400
                }
            });
        });
        $ctCollContainer.colladjust();
        $ctCollContainer.find('div.ct-coll-item-multi').collslider();
    };
    return { init: init };
})();
CollManag.init();
}); 
</script>
```

And here is one of the conflicting scripts:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.sidebarlink').click(function(){
        if ($("#content").hasClass("sidebar-active")){
          $("#content").toggleClass("sidebar-active");
          $("#content").toggleClass("sidebar-active-1600");
          $(".sidebarbox").toggleClass("sidebar-active");
          $(".sidebarlink").css( "opacity", 1 );

        }else{
          $("#content").toggleClass("sidebar-active");
          $("#content").toggleClass("sidebar-active-1600");
          $(".sidebarbox").toggleClass("sidebar-active");
          $(".commentbox").removeClass("commentbox-active");
          $("#content").removeClass("commentbox-active");
          $("#content").removeClass("commentbox-active-1600");
          $(".sidebarlink").css( "opacity", 0 );
          $(".commentbox-link").css( "opacity", 1 );
        }return false;
      });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you see in console?

Comment: Could you clarify in what way it "breaks the rest of my javascript"?

Comment: chrome console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input masonry.js:16
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colladjust'

Comment: @KlasMellbourn scripts are working fine independently, but when combined, only the masonry works.

Answer (score 0):

Your non masonry script poison's masonry.js by defining variables it is using.  Find out which one it is by removing individual statements from the non masonry script until it begins working.

The solution may be as easy as changing the id and class variable names to something else.